# Bluetooth support in QuickBlox webRtc sdk Android

Tags: android, quickblox

I am using Quick Blox android Sdk for calling application .Calling is working fine but i got and issue . When my device is connected to bluetooth nothing happening on bluetooth neither the mic nor the speaker. I have searched the documentation of the sdk but found nothing there about bluetooth support .Does anyone knows how do i overcome this problem. I am currently using verion 3.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with QuickBlox Android SDK. The sample code, however, is not directly in the master of the QuickBlox repository, but in [this branch](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/feature/QBANDRSDK-Bluetooth).

There are only 2 differences to the repository master. Firstly, the bluetooth permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

But the really interesting code is in the class [CallActivity](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/compare/feature/QBANDRSDK-Bluetooth?diff=split&name=feature%2FQBANDRSDK-Bluetooth#diff-3615ee98de5792988f211362a28e6209).

With these changes, the Bluetooth connection worked for me with the Quick-Blox SDK 3.2 and 3.3.

You can also see the originall answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46892395/bluetooth-support-for-quickblox-android-sdk).

Regards