# Bluetooth support for QuickBlox Android SDK

Tags: android, bluetooth, quickblox, quickblox-android

Is there a bluetooth support for the Android API from QuickBlox?

This has already been asked a few times, but all without answer. The corresponding support for iOS was introduced already in [March 2016](https://quickblox.com/blog/ios-webrtc-video-chat-sdk-2-2-with-bluetooth-support/).

I have tested with 2 SDK versions (SDK 3.2 and 3.4), but still get the same problem: I could not get any sound from the Bluetooth headset.
The same code works easily with a wired headset. In addition, the Bluetooth headsets have worked with our test device, but only until the
start of the video chat.

The most promising QuickBlox API I found is the [AppRTCAudioManager Interface](https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android#Manage_Audio_settings). This works apparently only for wired headsets and buid in speakers. The selection of the audio device happens inside the QuickBlox library and can not be affected.

I would appreciate an explicit response, ideally from QuickBlox, since we have already received contradictory information.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can realize this functionality himself, QuickBlox has [test branch](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/feature/QBANDRSDK-Bluetooth) with needed functionality, but you should adapt it for your needs.

Comment: Thank you Valentyn, this is quite useful!
I've tried it with the SDK 3.2 and 3.3 and it works. The additional code in the CallActivity class does not seem to use specific QuickBlox APIs. Is that correct? This would mean, that these bluetooth adjustments tend to be independent of future QuickBlox SDK changes?

Comment: yes, you are correct, additional code not related with QuickBlox API and must work with newer versions, but you need read changelog before update to newest versions (maybe this functionality will be integrated to QuickBlox Android SDK)